# Looping through a list of strings in a pandas column

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file that I converted to a pandas data frame,

```
# Bring in data 
audit = pd.read_json('audit_2018-03-02.json')
```

Now, I have a few columns where the values of those columns are a list of strings.

```
    foo

    [By Audience, By Vendor]
    [By Month, By Keyword, By Ad Group, By Service]
    [By Month, By To Date, By Keyword, By Ad Group]
```

I am trying to loop through the column foo and create a data frame from this column.

I have tried,

```
list_of_records = [
    (i['By Month'],
     i['By Keyword'],
     i['By Ad Group'],
     i['By Audience'],
     i['By Vender'],
     i['By Week'],
     i['By To Date'],
     i['By Creative'],
     i['By Strategy'],
     i['By Converstion'],
     i['By Geo'],
     i['By Campaign']
    )
    for i, in zip(audit['foo'])
]

Dimensions_Measured = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
list_of_records,
columns = ['By Month', 'By Keyword', 'By Ad Group', 'By Audience', 'By Vender', 
           'By Week', 'By To Date', 'By Creative', 'By Strategy', 'By Converstion', 
           'By Geo', 'By Campaign']
    )
```

But I get an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Any Ideas on how to achieve this??

Should I do some sort of One Hot Encoding and then create the data frame?

Comment: how your output should looks like??

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a series of lists into a multiple series via `pd.Series.values.tolist()`:

```
foo = pd.Series([['By Audience', 'By Vendor'],
                 ['By Month', 'By Keyword', 'By Ad Group', 'By Service'],
                 ['By Month', 'By To Date', 'By Keyword', 'By Ad Group']])

df = pd.DataFrame(foo.values.tolist())

#              0           1            2            3
# 0  By Audience   By Vendor         None         None
# 1     By Month  By Keyword  By Ad Group   By Service
# 2     By Month  By To Date   By Keyword  By Ad Group
```